# Bayesian updating based on the observed sum of bernouilli variables

Tags: bayesian

I am struggling with the following problem, and i am wondering what the best way to tackle it is.

Imagine we have a population of a 100 patients, of which 30 have a prior estimated probability of 20% to be "infected", 30 have a 50% estimated probability, and the remaining 40 have an estimated probability of 70% to be infected. These probabilities are our prior best estimate at the moment. unfortunately, we do not know which individual patients fall into which category. We take a sample of the population (e.g. 10 patients), and notice that 7 are infected.

What is the best methodology or framework to update our probabilities to account for this new information?

Comment: Is this `self-study`?

Comment: is the population actually finite, i.e., are you sampling without replacement 10 individuals from a population of 100 individuals? Or was the reference to 100 patients just an informal way to say that each individual in the population has probability $p_1=0.3,\ p_2=0.3,\ p_3=0.4$ of belonging to group $G_1,G_2,G_3$? Also, can we assume that all the patients in the sample belong to one of the three groups? In this case, the problem becomes the very simple updating of the subgroup probability. Instead, if each of the 10 patients can belong to a different group, this becomes much more messy IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may seem complicated at first, but it may be easily simplified to something more familiar.

As I understand, you have $N$ patients in three groups of sizes $n_1 = 30, n_2 = 30, n_3 = 40$ and based on your best knowledge you can assume *a priori* susceptibility for the disease in those groups to be $\mu_1 = 0.2, \mu_2 = 0.5, \mu_3 = 0.7$. You sample without replacement $m = 10$ patients from the whole population and observe that $k = 7$ are infected.

First thing to notice is that *a priori* you can assume that the probability of seeing infected patient from the $i$-th group is $\pi_i = n_i/N \times \mu_i$, since it is probability of sampling a patient from the $i$-th group $n_i/N$ times the prior probability of getting infected $\mu_i$. We multiply those probabilities since the two events are independent. Next thing to notice is that, a patient can belong to either of the groups, so the probability of getting infected in the total sample is $\pi = \pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3$, and so, the expected number of infected patients in the whole population is $\pi N$.

Since you do not have the group labels for the patients in your sample and you have only aggregate data, you need to focus on the estimates for the whole population rather then on the groups. What you can assume *a priori* is that the population-wide risk of infection is $\pi$. The probability of finding an infected patient in your sample can be approximated using binomial distribution parametrized by sample size $m$ and and probability of infection $p$ (the fact that $m/N\le0.1$ also justifies such approximation of hypergeometric distribution). The parameter $p$ is unknown and is to be estimated, but *a priori* we can assume that $E(p) = \pi$ and that it follows a beta distribution with some parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\pi = \tfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$. Since the parameters of beta distribution can be thought as "pseudocounts" of successes and failures and we have pretty clear idea of what we are expecting to see in our experiment, we cen set them to the expected counts $\alpha = m\pi$ and $\beta = m(1-\pi)$. Updating the *prior* is easy since beta is a conjugate prior for binomial, so the *posterior* parameters become $\alpha' = m\pi + k$ and $\beta' = m(1-\pi) + (m-k)$, and the *posterior* expected probability of infection is

$$ E(p) = \frac{m\pi + k}{ m\pi + m(1-\pi) + m } $$

This leads to the posterior distribution as illustrated bellow, that falls nicely somewhere in-between your prior and likelihood.

[image: Prior, likelihood and posterior distributions]

As about splitting the probabilities among groups, nothing has changed after seeing the data as compared to your prior knowledge since you don't know what groups did the patients come from. So if you *need* to split, then I guess the best you can do is to act according to your prior knowledge and split the probabilities proportionally to how the infected patients would be splitted a priori, i.e. proportionally to $\pi_i/\pi$ for $i$-th group.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How would one update, if we assume that the group sizes have not changed, the proportions (20%, 50%, 70%) in the individual groups. Clearly - the expected value of the posterior has shifted (from 48% in the prior to ~60% in the posterior). Does that mean that we should update the group proportions with +12%? or is there a more principled or other way to do this?

Comment: @user1885116 your data does not provide any information about this so any way you update will have more in common with your prior expectations. You could divide it proportionally to group sizes, or proportionally to prior probabilities etc. there is no "good" or "bad" choices since in fact you don't know what is more or less appropriate. So if you really *need* to divide it, then you have to ask yourself what makes more sense according to your best knowledge. The data only permits you to make population-wide inference. Of course, it would be different if you had more data etc.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in one of my comments, your problems seems to me either very simple (basically, just a simplified case of the classic Beta-Binomial conjugate model) or really complicated (for me). I'll go with the simple solution: let me know if that's what you were looking for.

You have groups $G_1,G_2,G_3$ with respective disease probabilities $\theta_1=0.2,\ \theta_2=0.5,\ \theta_3=0.7$. The prior probabilities that a patient belong to group $G_i, \ i=1,\dots,3$ are respectively $p_1=0.3,\ p_2=0.3,\ p_3=0.4$. Assumptions:

- infinite population (or at least of size much larger than 10). In other words, I assume that your reference to 100 patients was just an informal way to define subgroup probabilities, not that you are sampling **without** replacement from a group of 100 patients. This also allow modeling the events "Patient $i$ is infected" as independent for $i=1,\dots,10$ if the patients are sampled randomly. If the population were finite, then the infection probabilities would definitely not be the same for each observation. In view of these assumptions (infinite population & random sampling) I will model the sample as i.i.d.
- all the individuals in the sample come from the same group. This is quite a **strong** assumption: it means that your research question is, "I know that I sampled one of the population groups, but **I don't know which group**: I only know that 7 out of 10 are infected. Then, what is the probability that the sample came from group $G_1$? What is the probability that the sample came from group $G_2$?" (of course the probability that the sample came from $G_3$ is just 1 minus the other two probabilities). I don't know if this hypothesis makes sense for you: it depends on your sampling process.

Anyway, if these two assumptions make sense for you, then the solution is simple.  Let $Y$ be the binomial random variable counting the number of infected individuals in your sample. You want

$$p(G_i|Y=7)=\frac{p(Y=7|G_i)p(G_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^3p(Y=7|G_i)p(G_i)},\quad i=1,2$$

Clearly

$$p(Y=7|G_1)=\binom{10}{7}\theta_1^7(1-\theta_1)^{(10-7)}=\binom{10}{7}0.2^7 \cdot 0.8^3 = 0.000786432$$
$$p(Y=7|G_2)=\binom{10}{7}\theta_2^7(1-\theta_2)^{(10-7)}=\binom{10}{7}0.5^7 \cdot 0.5^3 = 0.1171875$$
$$p(Y=7|G_3)=\binom{10}{7}\theta_3^7(1-\theta_3)^{(10-7)}=\binom{10}{7}0.7^7 \cdot 0.7^3 = 0.2668279$$

Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^3p(Y=7|G_i)p(G_i)=0.000786432*p_1+0.1171875*p_2+0.2668279*p_3=0.1421234$$

And

$$p(G_1|Y=7)=\frac{0.000786432*p_1}{0.1421234}=0.001660034$$
$$p(G_2|Y=7)=\frac{0.1171875*p_2}{0.1421234}=0.2473643$$

Thus

$$p(G_3|Y=7)=1-p(G_1|Y=7)-p(G_2|Y=7)=1-0.001660034-0.2473643=0.7509756$$

Thus you have approximately a 75.1% probability that the sample came from group $G_3$, a 24.7% probability that the sample came from group $G_2$, and just a 0.17% probability that the sample came from group $G_1$.